# System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: SQL, Actual: null

Tags: apex, deployment, failing-tests

I have the following test class LeadTriggerTest which fails with the following error:

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: SQL, Actual: null
>   Class.LeadTriggerTest.converted_opp_contacts_are_sql: line 31, column 1

Below is the code:

```
@isTest
private class LeadTriggerTest {

    // When a lead is converted to an opportunity, the Contact.Qualified__c 
    // for contacts related to the new opportunity should be set to SQL
    @isTest static void converted_opp_contacts_are_sql() {
        // Create lead
        Lead l = new Lead();
        l.LastName = 'TestLastName';
        l.Company = 'Test Company';
        insert l;

        // Make sure no opportunities in DB
        System.assertEquals(0, [ SELECT Count() FROM Opportunity ])<br>
        // Convert lead
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(l.Id);
        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);

        // Make sure opportunities in DB and converted contact
        // has right value in Qualified__c

        Opportunity o = [ SELECT Id FROM Opportunity ];
        Contact c = [ SELECT Qualified__c FROM Contact
                      WHERE Id = :lcr.contactId ];

        system.debug(' contact value ' +   c.Qualified__c);

        System.assertEquals('SQL', c.Qualified__c);
    }
}
```

Apex Trigger:

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after update) {

    if (Trigger.IsUpdate && Trigger.IsAfter) {

        // Collect contact IDs from converted leads
        List<Id> contactIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
            if (l.IsConverted && !Trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).isConverted) {
                contactIds.add(l.ConvertedContactId);
            }
        }

        List<Contact> newContacts = [ SELECT Qualified__c 
                                      FROM Contact 
                                      WHERE Id IN :contactIds ];

        for (Contact newContact : newContacts) {
            newContact.Qualified__c = 'SQL';
        }

        update newContacts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please provide your trigger code. Apparently, that's where the error comes from.

Comment: Could you add this line at the end of the test to make sure your lead field IsConverted is set to true?
System.assertEquals(true, l.isConverted);

Comment: @MartinLezer Thankx , And do I need to remove the assert already written to make the test go fine

Comment: Your current assert seems to be important. I just asked you to add the other assertion to check if your trigger is supposed to update the contacts list.

Comment: The new system.assert still fails System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: SQL, Actual: null
Class.LeadTriggerTest.converted_opp_contacts_are_sql: line 31, column 1

Comment: Are your sure that you have a lead status with IsConverted = true on your lead object in the picklist?
If so, could you add this assertion and tell me if it returns no error?
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

Comment: @MartinLezer When I try to deploy after removing the system.assert it fails with the following message:System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: SQL, Actual: Suspect 
Stack Trace: Class.LeadTriggerTest.converted_opp_contacts_are_sql: line 28, column 1  Is there anything that can be done

Comment: Immediately after you instantiate `lcr`, add `system.assert(lcr.isSuccess(), lcr.getErrors())`. If this assertion fails it will tell you why your conversion isn't happening.

Comment: (1) do you have any field updates (workflow/process builder) on `Contact.qualified__c` that might be resetting the value from `SQL` to null? (2) You are not checking to see if `update newContacts` succeeds; (3) You are not checking to see if the `LeadConvert` succeeds. (4) The test for oldMap not converted is unnecessary as converted leads are read only - see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm?search_text=user .  As an aside, the first assert for 0 Oppos is unnecessary as you are in `SeeAllData=false` test context.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you need to also fetch the record `Id` alongside `Qualified__c`?

For example:

```
for (Contact newContact : [
    SELECT Id, Qualified__c 
    FROM Contact 
    WHERE Id IN :contactIds
]) {
    newContact.Qualified__c = 'SQL';
}

update newContacts;
```

Comment: Id is always returned in `Apex` queries, whether you specify it or not.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, was just a hunch. As for those: next time, test 'em first.